# REST API for IoT Edge module twins?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

What is the corresponding REST API to read and update the twins of Azure IoT Edge modules? For IoT devices [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/devicetwinapi/getdevicetwin) works. So far I only can see the twins in the portal and via the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading Module Twin, the format of REST API for is `/twins/${deviceId}/modules/${moduleId}?api-version=${IoTHubApiVersion}`. You could refer to the [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-iot-toolkit/blob/267a47c313e53b47ecd9d61348687dd9ed1bdaa2/src/utility.ts#L195) in Azure IoT Toolkit extension for reference to learn how it reads Module Twin.

Comment: Ah, my guess was right after all :) The important piece is the the correct API version 2017-11-08-preview. I added that in your answer